# Invisible element and Col-X elements with Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to make invisible a checkbox input with bootstrap 4 between some cols elements.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <a class="col-2">
      1 of 2
    </a>
    <input type="checkbox" class="invisible" >
    <input type="text" class="col-10" value="2 of 2">
  </div>  
</div>
```

I used the `invisible` class and it is not visible, but it has a size of 13px.

[image]

[image]

How can I use cols elements to fill the row with an hidden element in the middle?

This is an example of what I have:
https://jsfiddle.net/j6h93rve/1/

And this is what I want:
https://jsfiddle.net/fybmkp7e/

Comment: sorry, it's not clear what you are expecting?

Comment: I want to fill a row using col-2 and a col-10 elements, but in the middle there will be an hidden element. This hidden element make a raw wrap.

Comment: Instead of `invisible` use `d-none` class

Comment: This is the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you have to use [`d-none`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/display/#hiding-elements) instead of [`invisible`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/visibility/) class

- `d-none` - `display: none`
- `invisible` - `visibility: hidden`

[**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/aswinkumar863/ec4futbp/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `invisible` you can use `d-none` class, will work.